# How to call different data files using a for loop in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of files named such as

```
topaccount_2015_09_individuals
topaccount_2015_12_indiviuuals
...
topaccount_2021_12_individuals
```

which are subsets of

```
topaccount_2015_09
topaccount_2015_12
...
topaccount_2021_12
```

I want to call them and do some data manipulation so i created a list,

```
known_series = known['Address']
y = ['2015_09', '2015_12', '2016_03', '2016_06', '2016_09', '2016_12', '2017_03', '2017_06', '2017_09', '2017_12',
     '2018_03', '2018_06', '2018_09', '2018_12', '2019_03', '2019_06', '2019_09', '2019_12' , '2020_03', '2020_06', '2020_09', '2020_12', 
     '2021_03', '2021_03', '2021_06', '2021_09', '2021_12']

for q in y:
    topaccount_[q]_individuals = topaccount_[q][~topaccount_[q]['address'].isin(known_series)]
    topaccount_[q]_individuals = topaccount_[q]_individuals.reset_index(drop=True)
```

but it is giving me an error. what am I doing wrong? (known_series is already defined in the script)

UPDATE
I followed the suggestion below, but i have one more problem, which is how to address the master dataframe from which I am extracting _individuals dataframes.

```
y = ['2015_09', '2015_12', '2016_03', '2016_06', '2016_09', '2016_12', '2017_03', '2017_06', '2017_09', '2017_12',
     '2018_03', '2018_06', '2018_09', '2018_12', '2019_03', '2019_06', '2019_09', '2019_12' , '2020_03', '2020_06', '2020_09', '2020_12', 
     '2021_03', '2021_03', '2021_06', '2021_09', '2021_12']

file_individuals = []
file = []

for x in y:
    file_individuals.append(f'topaccount_{x}_individuals')
    file.append(f'topaccount_{x}')
    
print(file_individuals)
print(file)
    
for file_individuals in file_individuals:
    file_individuals = **topaccount_[q][~topaccount_[q]**['address'].isin(known_series)]  
    file_individuals = file_individuals[~file_individuals['address'].isin(coinmarketcap_series)]
    file_individuals = file_individuals[~file_individuals['address'].isin(tord_series)]
    file_individuals = file_individuals[~file_individuals['address'].isin(exchanges_series)]
    file_individuals = file_individuals.reset_index(drop=True)
```

REUPDATE

```
d = {}
names=[]
for x in y:
     d['ind'] = f"topaccount_{x}_individuals"
     d['top'] = f"topaccount_{x}"
     names.append(d)
    
for n in names:
    n['ind'] = n['top'][~n['top']['address'].isin(known_series)]
```

and I get the following error:

```
   n['ind'] = n['top'][~n['top']['address'].isin(known_series)]

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Maybe `known_series` is already defined but your example is not reproducible. You can't create variables dynamically like that `topaccount_[q]_individuals`.

Comment: so I have to do everything manually?

Comment: No you can use a dictionary `topaccount_individuals` indexed by `y`

Comment: You mean this file `topaccount_[q]`?

Comment: exactly. I am not sure how to address them since their date have to match. (i.e. extracting top_account_2012_12_individuals from top_account_2012_12

Comment: Alternative added in edited answer.

Comment: Thanks Devang, but I get the following error msg: TypeError: string indices must be integers .... when trying to execute "for n in names:....

Comment: Ah right, because it is infact a string, not the real file.  So, referencing data in it with [] will not be possible.

Comment: But, you would have to read these files first, right?

Comment: If you read the files first into a dataframe and then continue with processing, it should be okay.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this then and use the name list later.

```
name = []
for x in y:
    name.append(f'topaccount_{x}_individuals') 
    
print(name)

['topaccount_2015_09_individuals', 'topaccount_2015_12_individuals', 'topaccount_2016_03_individuals', 'topaccount_2016_06_individuals', 'topaccount_2016_09_individuals', 'topaccount_2016_12_individuals', 'topaccount_2017_03_individuals', 'topaccount_2017_06_individuals', 'topaccount_2017_09_individuals', 'topaccount_2017_12_individuals', 'topaccount_2018_03_individuals', 'topaccount_2018_06_individuals', 'topaccount_2018_09_individuals', 'topaccount_2018_12_individuals', 'topaccount_2019_03_individuals', 'topaccount_2019_06_individuals', 'topaccount_2019_09_individuals', 'topaccount_2019_12_individuals', 'topaccount_2020_03_individuals', 'topaccount_2020_06_individuals', 'topaccount_2020_09_individuals', 'topaccount_2020_12_individuals', 'topaccount_2021_03_individuals', 'topaccount_2021_03_individuals', 'topaccount_2021_06_individuals', 'topaccount_2021_09_individuals', 'topaccount_2021_12_individuals']
```

> 

Alternatively,

```
d = {}
names=[]
for x in y:
     d['ind'] = f"topaccount_{x}_individuals"
     d['top'] = f"topaccount_{x}"
     names.append(d)

for n in names:
    n['ind'] = n['top'].....
```

Comment: The very first line is calling data from the master file, "topaccount_2015_12[~topaccount_2015_12['address'].isin(known_series)]" how can I approach this?? do I specify a loop inside a loop??

Comment: You can create these file names before and then use them in the code.

Comment: yes i understand that, but these are two different sets of files. `code`

y = ['2015_09', '2015_12', '2016_03', '2016_06', '2016_09', '2016_12', '2017_03', '2017_06', '2017_09', '2017_12',
     '2018_03', '2018_06', '2018_09', '2018_12', '2019_03', '2019_06', '2019_09', '2019_12' , '2020_03', '2020_06', '2020_09', '2020_12', 
     '2021_03', '2021_03', '2021_06', '2021_09', '2021_12']

file_individuals = []
file = []

for x in y:
    file_individuals.append(f'topaccount_{x}_individuals')
    file.append(f'topaccount_{x}')